# Implicit conversion to double in C

Tags: c

I am trying to understand implicit conversion in C .I have the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int a = -6 ;
    size_t b = 100 ;
    int result = a*b ; /* a is converted to size_t,
    multiply two unsigned ints and cast the result to int
    */
    double dresult = a*b ;
    printf("Result : %d \n",result); //         Output  Result : -600 
    printf("Double Result : %f \n",dresult); // Output  Double Result : 18446744073709551616.000000 
    return 0;
}
```

From what I understood from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion), the `result` should be some garbage (as printed when converted to double) value, but why does it give me the right value?

Comment: Are you sure that `a` is converted to `size_t`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 In cppreference, it is given as "If the unsigned type has conversion rank greater than or equal to the rank of the signed type, then the operand with the signed type is implicitly converted to the unsigned type. ", so I assume it is converted to size_t

Comment: "should be some garbage" I'm pretty sure cppreference doesn't say anything similar to this. Can you quote the actual words that made you arrive to this conclusion?

Comment: cppreferecne also says *"if the target type is signed, the behavior is implementation-defined"*  So you will have to check your compiler's manual to see how the int could become -600.

Comment: `size_t` is unsigned, and your `18446744073709551616` is equivalent to `-600` (2^64 - 600).

Comment: @n.m. I was assuming that ```int result = a*b``` will trigger undefined behaviour when ```int``` is assigned with ```18446744073709551616``` If I understood correctly,  It is also mentioned in *Real floating-integer conversions* : " If the resulting value can be represented by the target type, that value is used otherwise, the behavior is undefined 
"

Comment: "Undefined" doesn't mean "will crash" or "will yield bizarre behavior".  It's true that the unsigned number 18446744073709551016 can't be represented as a signed int.  But what you typically get (especially on popular two's complement machines) is the same bit pattern, truncated and interpreted as a signed int, which is -600 again.

Comment: That number you got for `dresult` isn't "garbage", either; it's that same number 18446744073709551016, rounded to the 53-bit available precision of type `double`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SteveSummit. What I understood from your comments is that : It  does (2^64-a)*b  = 2^64*b-a*b. Now 2^64*b is rounded to 2^64, so we get 2^64-a*b as pointed out in the above comment from WeatherVane ?

Comment: @WeatherVane: 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 is 2^64, not 2^64−600. The latter is 18,446,744,073,709,551,016.

Comment: @AdityaKurrodu: Re “I was assuming that `int result = a*b` will trigger undefined behaviour when int is assigned with `18446744073709551616`. If I understood correctly, It is also mentioned in *Real floating-integer conversions* : " If the resulting value can be represented by the target type, that value is used otherwise, the behavior is undefined”: The conversion of `a*b` to initialize `result` is a conversion from an integer type (likely `size_t`) to an integer type (`int`). It is not a real floating-integer conversion.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Conversion from an integer-type out-of-range value to a signed-integer type is implementation-defined, not undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes that is true. OP's code comment is that 2^64 was output, and my local compilation also output 2^64, and not 2^64  - 600. Although the compiler did warn about possible loss of data converting `size_t` to `double`, and of course the value 2^64 cannot be held by a 64-bit `size_t`.

Comment: "Undefined behaviour" does not mean the result will be garbage, it means the standard is not telling you anything about the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When evaluating the expression `a*b`, the [usual arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) are applied to both operands. This means that

- on platforms on which `size_t` has equal or higher rank than `int` (which is the case on most platforms), `a` is converted to `size_t`. Since `size_t` is unsigned, the value of `a` (which is `-6`) will be converted to an unsigned value. On platforms on which `size_t` is 64-bit, this value will be `18446744073709551610`. Multiplying this value of `a` with the value of `b` (which is `100`) will yield the mathematical result `1844674407370955161000`, which is not representable in a 64-bit `size_t`. Therefore, assuming a 64-bit `size_t`, the actual result will be the mathematical result modulo `18446744073709551616` (2 to the power 64), which is `18446744073709551016`. On platforms on which `size_t` is 32-bit, the corresponding result is `4294966696`. Note that this "overflow" will not invoke undefined behavior, because only signed integer overflow will invoke undefined behavior. Unsigned integer overflow is well-defined.
- on platforms on which `size_t` has a rank less than `int` (which are theoretically possible and permitted by the ISO C standard, but unlikely to exist in practice), `a` will not be converted to `size_t`, so the result will be simply `-600`.

For the reasons stated above, depending on which platform you are using, the result of `a*b` will likely be either `18446744073709551016`, `4294966696` or `-600`.

The line

```
double dresult = a*b ;
```

will therefore likely write either the value `18446744073709551016.0`, `4294966696.0` or `-600.0` to `dresult`, depending on which platform you are using. On your platform, the number `18446744073709551016.0` does not seem to be exactly representable in a `double` due to [floating-point inaccuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/12149471), so that it gets rounded to `18446744073709551616.0`.

With the line

```
int result = a*b ;
```

the situation is not quite as simple. On platforms on which `a*b` evaluates to `-600`, it is clear that the value `-600` will be written to `result`. However, on platforms on which `a*b` evaluates to `18446744073709551016`, the problem is that this value is not representable in an `int`, assuming that an `int` is 32-bit. In that case, according to [§6.3.1.3 ¶3 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3), the value written to `result` is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised. However, on most platforms, the result is simply the value that is obtained by repeatedly subtracting the maximum number representable in the unsigned version of the target type, plus one, until the result is in the range representable by the type. Therefore, the result would be `18446744073709551016 - 18446744073709551616`, which is `-600`. This appears to also be how your platform is behaving.

Comment: To be complete, `double dresult = a*b;` could produce a different result than 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 if `double` were decimal or some other base. However, 2^64−600 is necessarily within the finite `double` range (the C standard requires at least 10^37), so the conversion is defined. The only opportunities I see for undefined behavior are a trap in the conversion to `int` or a `size_t` that is so absurdly wide it exceeds the finite range of `double`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I'm not sure what you mean when you write that `"a trap in the conversion to int"` could cause undefined behavior. If an implementation-defined signal is raised according to [§6.3.1.3 ¶3 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3), wouldn't that be implementation-defined behavior instead of undefined behavior? Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: You are correct; I was thinking of a trap, but the standard requires the implementation to produce an implementation-defined `int` value or an implementation-defined signal, not to trap.